# Set the mouse location

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mouse-cursor

I need to be able to set the mouse location to the middle of the screen/window.
How can I do that?

Comment: I think this is one of those things where there is no straightforward way to do it because it isn't a very user-friendly thing to do.

Comment: I don't think that setting the mouse location to a certain point would be very useful... but then again I'm not too sure what you want out of your program...

Comment: There is no elegant way to do this, because doing this is extremely user-unfriendly.

Comment: Can you explain your end goal? There might be another way to achieve it.

Comment: I'm making an openGL game. I need to set the cursor to the middle of the window/screen.

Comment: In that case, you'll also want to use CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition so that you don't need to call CGWarpMouseCursorPosition every frame.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation seems to indicate that [CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint) or [CGWarpMouseCursorPosition](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGWarpMouseCursorPosition) will do what you're after.

*EDIT:* To match your latest comment, I would further recommend `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition`, about which the docs state:

> For example, this function is often used to move the cursor position
>   back to the center of the screen by games that do not want the cursor
>   pinned by display edges.

Comment: Just tried this. Thank you for your help but this function seems to override my mouse handler in my game.

Comment: @ChaseWalden, By "override" you mean what exactly? They are no longer called?

Comment: yeah. It responds for maybe 2-3 frames and then locks up.

Answer (score 4):

I was working on something like that last week.

```
  CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState);
  CGEventRef mouse = CGEventCreateMouseEvent (NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved, CGPointMake( X, Y), 0);
  CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, mouse);
  CFRelease(mouse);
  CFRelease(source);
```

Just set X and Y.

EDIT:

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
```

Comment: This (so far) works great for me. I use this along with [NSCursor hide] in an application to launch shuffled full screen videos (for machines setup as installations that have no user interaction). Doing so allows me to prevent the mouse from being visible or hovering over the menu bar.