# How to simulate a Keyboard/Mouse key press?

Tags: macos, mono, keypress, simulate

I am working on a Mac OS X project. I am using Mono Mac. I want to simulate a keyboard key press and mouse key press and move just similar to the approach we were using in Windows forms ([DllImport("user32.dll")] ....)

I found some Obj-C solution but I cannot port it to Mono Mac.
Some of them are in this stack link:
[Set the mouse location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059667/set-the-mouse-location)

Comment: Would be helpful if you linked to the Obj-C solution that you're trying to port, as well as a little bit more information about what you're trying to do. DllImport("user32.dll") could mean many different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I my self found the answer! You need to P/Invoke the required classes in the ObjC (in the CoreGraphics) which you can easily do this in Mono as the following code demonstrates:

```
[DllImport(Constants.CoreGraphicsLibrary)]
```

Regards,
Peyman Mortazavi